# Angular 13 Service define structure

Tags: angular, service, angular-services, angular13

Literally very new to Angular13. Our application need some configuration data on startup, so Shared service to be called out on AppComponent and its data will be shared around application header, menu and footer to show/hide few div's. Below is the sample code of SharedService.
**Shared.service.ts**

````
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  
  private data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  data$: Observable<any> = this.data.asObservable();

  private companyLogo: string = '';
  private languages: string = 'en-us';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('/shared').subscribe(data => {
      //let us say data will be like 
      data = {
        "logourl" : '/img/mg1.jpg',
        "showDashboard": true,
        "language": 'en',
        "username": 'user-1', //so on and it has 20+ values
      }
      //How to structure this data and called throughout application
    })
  }

}```
I have no idea that how to use return data whether to get it through observables/getter/setter. Guide me in implementing this.
````

Comment: Take a look at how BehaviorSubject works https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject . Other components would then need to import this service and access the data$ Observable.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to a BehaviorSubject (or any Subject) you need to call `.next()` method and pass the data as a parameter:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  
  private data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  private companyLogo: string = '';
  private languages: string = 'en-us';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('/shared').subscribe(data => {

      data.next({
        "logourl" : '/img/mg1.jpg',
        "showDashboard": true,
        "language": 'en',
        "username": 'user-1', //so on and it has 20+ values
      })

    })
  }

  getData(){
    return data.asObservable();
  }

  //...
```

To get the data from other places in your app:

```
// after injecting service..
this.sharedService.getData().subscribe(data => {
  // handle data
}
```